# C# multi threaded or multi process?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, multiprocessing

I have a small question about multithreaded connections between one (Server) to many (Clients) relationship.

My question is:

- Is my script multithreaded? Or Multi process? I have received some feedback stating that it is multiprocess?
- Would each client receive their stream independently?
- I'd just like to know if this is the correct approach to this.

Here you can see I start to listen to client connections and create a thread for each client connection and I pass the client :

```
private void StartListen()
{
    //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
    tcpListener.Start();

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
    int counter = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            clientList.Add(client);
            IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            //Updating status of connection
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from " + IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());

            th_inPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { inPutStream(client, counter); });
            th_inPutStream.Start();

            counter++;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Cleanup_dep();
        }
    }
}
```

- This is where I handle the client `input stream` where i pre-process the client input stream:

```
private void inPutStream(TcpClient client, int clientID)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            NetworkStream networkstream = client.GetStream();

            if (networkstream.DataAvailable == true)
            {
                int messageID = 0;
                int messageSize = 0;
                int bufferSize = 100;

                //First retrieve size of header
                byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[4];
                int bytes = networkstream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, 4);
                int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeBytes, 0);

                //Read stream containing header with message details
                byte[] header = new byte[dataLength];
                int headerbyte = networkstream.Read(header, 0, dataLength);
                string headerString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header, 0, headerbyte);

                // Process Message information ie Message ID & Message Size
                string[] headerSplit = headerString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                
                foreach (string s in headerSplit)
                {
                    if (s.Contains(":"))
                    {
                        headers.Add(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(":")), s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":") + 1));
                    }
                }
                
                //Fetch Message ID & Size
                messageSize = Convert.ToInt32(headers["len"]);
                messageID = Convert.ToInt32(headers["MsgId"]);

                //Filter actions by Message ID
                if (messageID == 1)//Machine info
                {
                    string machineinfo = receiveMessage(messageSize, bufferSize, networkstream);
                    clientNames.Add(machineinfo.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })[0]);
                    updateClientListUI();
                }
                
                if (messageID == 2)//CMD Commands
                {
                    cmdres = receiveMessage(messageSize, bufferSize, networkstream);
                    activeForm.updateText(cmdres);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Cleanup_dep();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see the part where your program creates threads and starts them? that's multithreading

Comment: So why am I being told this is multi process? I just wanted reassurance on this. Thanks!

Comment: Multi-process requires creating new processes. In C# this can be done using the `Process` class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0). I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: Multi-process is when you have more than one process (running copy of the program), multi-threading is when you have more than one thread. If you had two processes you'd see them both in Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for your answers... but would you know why in inpustream method only listens to the last client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you are using `Thread` and not `Process` I don't see any indication as to why this would be a multi process approach.
- Without knowing how `TcpClient.GetStream` is exactly implemented, I would be suprised if the call on one client would have anything to do with the same call on another client. Other than obvious, unavoidable, coherences like sharing the same bandwidth if the connections are accepted on the same nic of course.
- Depends on what you are trying to do. If this is for work, I would question if there isn't an existing solution you could use. If this is for education there are a few improvements that come to mind:

  - use `async` and `Task` instead of `Thread` is usually recommended
  - `using var networkstream = client.GetStream();` will make sure the stream is disposed of correctly

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The issue that I get is that the inPutStream method only seems to be listening to the last client connection?

Comment: That is almost certainly not due to `client.GetStream();`. Without debugging the full code I  can only make educated guesses though. One thing that sticks out to me is that you are overwriting some reference with `client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();` instead of creating a new variable. I have not used threads in a while and can´t remember if references can permeate from one to another but maybe its worth a shot trying?

Comment: I had lready stored TcpClient client; But i guess this is for a follow up question.